# How to include css in html using php

Tags: php, html, css, font-face

I'm including css using php 
like

```
<?php include "css/cssnew.css"; ?>
```

But Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares

**css:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    src: url(/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}

.fa-angle-double-up:before {
    content: '\f102';
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why that fa-angle-double-up:before is not showing

```
        content: '\f102';
```

Comment: you're attempting to include a css file as a php script. your php should instead output the correct html element for loading a css file.

Comment: `<?php echo '<link href="css/cssnew.css" rel="stylesheet">'; ?>` ??

Comment: Question don't you have one html file that you load in your php file?

Comment: @Bijesh Samani I have edited my answer as per your comment

Answer (score 2):

I know, there are 3 method for adding CSS to HTML and echo with PHP:

1. Use link:

`<?php echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />';`

In this method, you can add your CSS codes in CSS file `style.css` and echo HTML `<link>` with PHP.

2. Embedding CSS into the HTML:

`<?php echo '<style media="screen" type="text/css">Add style rules here</style>'; ?>`

Example:

```
<?php echo '<style media="screen" type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:FontAwesome;src:url(/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont);font-weight:400;font-style:normal}.fa{display:inline-block;font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;font-size:inherit;text-rendering:auto;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.fa-angle-double-up:before{content:"\f102"}</style>'; ?>
```

3. Last method:

`<style><?php include "css/cssnew.css"; ?></style>`

Or

```
<?php 
echo '<style>'; 
include "css/cssnew.css"; 
echo '</style>'
;?>
```

Comment: I have external style sheet 
I want to include it my page itself using php 
Styles are rendering properly except fa icon

Comment: I have problem only with icon

Comment: All the styles are loading except icon

Comment: Check if your font gets loaded (or a 404 is returned) by using your web inspector in your browser. The path to your font, according to your CSS posted above is: `/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont` . Is this the correct filename?

Comment: @BijeshSamani Do you have any error (404 or 403) in web browser console?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CSS with  tag.

```
<style>
    <?php 
         include 'css/cssnew.css'; 
    ?>
</style>
```

you can also use HTML  tag.

```
<?php
echo '<link href="css/cssnew.css" rel="stylesheet">';
?>
```

Comment: Yes i tried with 
<style>
    <?php 
         include 'css/cssnew.css'; 
    ?>
</style>

Comment: Styles are rendering 
except fa icon

Answer (score 1):

Well I saw this two options. I hope it helps.

```html
<?php echo '<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">'; ?>

<!-- or -->

<style><? include_once ”PATH/your_style.css" media ="" ?></style> 
// <style><? require_once ”PATH/your_style.css" media ="" ?></style>

<!--Good Luck I hope it helps!-->
```

Answer (score 0):

As your comment says, You can save below php code as **newcss.php**

```
<?php echo '<link href="css/cssnew.css" rel="stylesheet">'; ?>
```

Now dynamically include in your PHP file as

```
<?php 
         include 'newcss.php'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

> Inside HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cssnew.css" type="text/css">
```

> Inside Php

```
<?php echo '<link href="css/cssnew.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >'; ?>
```

Comment: But i want to include external css in my page itself 
So this is possible by using php include statement 
and it works except fa icon